# Call express route from angular frontend

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ejs

**1.** I'm trying to integrate a localAuthenticationStrategy (using **passport.js**) which I have made by following [scotch.io tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) in my already developed web app (using **nodeJs with express routing and angularJs $routeProvider for frontend roting**). My problem is any anchor tag from the ng-view my application **does not seem to hit the express route defined for /login in route.js**. How can I hit that from my application using a link or button?

I have used catch all at the end of my routes.js as below -

```
// route to handle all angular requests
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs');
});
```

**2.** I'm using **ejs for templating**. Now if I define the partials to be used in ng-view section in the appRoute.js as an ejs file, the content is **getting added without parsing**. What I mean to say is the ejs file is not able to parse the <% %> section and the entire section is getting rendered as it is. How can I make it to be parsed properly before rendering?

Comment: I have tried using **<form> with a post submit to the /login** and it is hitting the node route for /login but I don't think it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hit any endpoint just use the `$http` service...

```
$http.post('/login')
.then(function(res){
   // handle response
})
```

make sure you get the method correct, `$http.post` or `$http.get`...